# Python Flask sending response immediately

Tags: python, flask

I need to execute Process during request like below

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_process():
    print "starting new process"
    p = Process(target=do_long_extra_job)
    p.start()

    return "this is response"
```

do_long_extra_job is on another process, so expected work flow is like this

1. start a process
2. response
3. long running extra job finished

but actual flow is like this

1. stat a process
2. long running extra job finished
3. response

how can I response immediately after starting new process?

Comment: You should look into using a task runner like [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) or [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this.

Comment: @jonafato But I can't use Celery or RQ either.

Comment: Why are these not options? They're probably better solutions in the long term than rolling your own version using multiprocessing.

Comment: @jonafato because system admin rejects to install these... :(

Answer (score -1):

The [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) method in the [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) class may work for you. 'Process' won't work for you in this case since it's a blocking method, meaning that your return statement will not execute until p.start() has finished executing.

Example with apply_async and multiprocessing.Pool:

```
def do_long_extra_job():
    #some extra long process
    return

@app.route('/test')
def test_process():
    print "starting new process"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    pool.apply_async(do_long_extra_job)
    return "this is response"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to add lines like this, `async_result = pool.apply_async(do_long_extra_job)`, `async_result.get()`. I don't know why `get()` is needed but it works.

Comment: Ok, It's not working :( Please reject my edit. I knew that `get()` is blocking and waiting results back, but It works first time... or looks like working.

Comment: Finally, I find out that  `Pool.apply_async` is not working on my production environment setup(using uwsgi / nginx). I need to tell my system admin to install Celery.