# AWS API Gateway send response and trigger lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack-api

I am connecting slack to an api gateway that triggers a lambda function.  In the slack api spec it says that events must have a 2XX response within 3 seconds so it is best to handle sending  the response to the event and the 2XX confirmation of receival response separate.  The solution I am thinking about right now would be to have an automatic 200 response from the api gateway when an event is received and also trigger a lambda function that could use the slack api to respond.  Is it possible to trigger a lambda function and have a different response that can be sent before the lambda is done executing?

A possible solution I have thought of is having a lambda function that returns 2XX receival response and then this lambda will call another lambda to send the actual response.  Is this the best solution?

Comment: The best solution depends on your requirements. In general I would suggest to put all incoming events in a queue.and return 200 OK. Then have a queue worker process to handle the actual events.

Comment: Sorry this might be a stupid question but how would I go about putting events into a queue.  Is this a feature of gateway?

Comment: There are many options. e.g. you can use the queue feature of asyncio in Pyhthon, or Amazons SQS service

Comment: another more simple approach is to just spawn a new process in Python for every event you receive. Let you original process send OK 200 and terminate and continue processing with the spawned process. see this for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response/51013358