# Slack Slash commands error: failed with the error "operation_timeout"

Tags: python, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api

I am using Slack Slash commands to send requests to my AWS Lambda python app.

However, after sending the command, Slack is returning the message `failed with the error "operation_timeout"`:

[image: operation_timeout]

Even though I received this message, my request is sent successfully, and the job is done.

I just want to know how to get rid of this message sent by slack.

I know that Slack expects an HTTP POST 200 OK as acknowledgement response as from this link [here](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#message_responses) but I did send one the moment the payload is received as shown here:

**lambda_handler.py**

```
def slack_acknowledgment_response(resonse_url):

    # Make API Call to Slack API
    requests.post(
        resonse_url, 
        {'text': 'Test'}
    )


# This is my main event
def main(event, context):

    payload = parse_qs(event['postBody'])

    response_url = payload['response_url'][0]

    slack_acknowledgment_response(response_url)

    time.sleep(5)
```

I intentionally added a sleep period of 5 seconds because I get this error if the runtime of my script takes longer than 3 seconds, even though I already sent an acknowledgement before 3 seconds.

Can someone please help out ?

Comment: Please share minimal code needed to reproduce please, we need to see the code.

Comment: I have updated the code with where i call it. Can you please help

Comment: Thanks! What is the timeout on the Lambda function? Have you changed it from the default 3 seconds? Try increasing to 10 seconds and see if that works (just glancing)

Comment: My lambda is 15 mins. I get the operation timeout from slack in 3 seconds. So i don't understand what's wrong

Comment: Your code is still not complete - can you please add details for `slack_acknowledgment_response`? Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: Dude. This is appearing unindented on stack overflow. My code is obviously indented during runtime...

Comment: I know but I can't properly copy and paste - this just makes it difficult for people to actually help. Your Python code all looks like one block. You should do your best in trying to help others to help you

Comment: I've formatted it. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Can someone please help out

Comment: How is this called? Is it being called? Maybe something is wrong with the API Gateway networking?

Comment: Your code is missing. Where is the function that gets the request? What calls main? Where is the code that accepts the http request?

Comment: different track to investigate: are you sure your AWS lambda is able to respond within that time?
it might be that you are hitting cold start instances that make your slack call timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your link, slack says [the 200 response message must be received within 3000ms](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#responding_basic_receipt) (3 seconds). However, I *think* you're misinterpreting the expectation. It want's the 200 response to *the request Slack sent to you*. You can send the [POST to the `response_url` within 30 seconds](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#message_responses), but it still needs to initial response within 3 seconds.

If you're expecting the process to take more than 3 seconds, you should probably figure out a way to do asynchronous processing. For example, queuing the jobs you received in Lambda to an SQS queue, then using the notification's `response_url` to send a response (as long as you can process it within 30 seconds).

You may want to look at [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56842007/451726) to see ways you can have your Lambda function return a response immediately, then do asynchronous processing via a second Lambda function.