# Handle request after response end putting it with sqlalchemy

Tags: multithreading, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

As I understand, there is no flask way to handle a request after request business logic that would process it, and put result in sqlalchemy.

I have looked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response) thread, and tried doing it with threads and it gives me this sqlalchemy app_context error:

> No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.

So the question is, how to do processing after response or may be how to push app_context into the thread?