# Make function not to wait for other function inside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a `flask` service as below:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import time


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/first", methods=["POST"])
def main():
    print("Request received")

    func1()

    return json.dumps({"status": True})


def func1():
    time.sleep(100)
    print("Print function executed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

So now when I make a request using **http://localhost:8080/first**

- control goes to main method and it prints `Request received` and wait for `func1` to get executed and then it returns `{"status": True}`

But now I don't want to wait for `func1` to finish its execution instead it will sent `{"status": True}` and `func1` will continue it's execution.

Comment: it sounds like a *fire-and-forget* approach. So, if you are interested in `asyncio` this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37278647/4636715

Comment: Try using celery http://www.celeryproject.org,In celery you can send your function to queue and continue with next line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to reply to request from flask, you need the decorated function to finish (in your case, that's `main`).

If you want to execute something in parallel, you need to execute it in another thread or a process. Multi-process apps are used to achieve more than a single CPU. (CPU bound); in your case, you just need it to execute in parallel so it is better to go with threads.

A simple technique is to use ThreadPool. import `ThreadPoolExecutor` from [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), then **submit** work to it, which allows your function execution code to continue. Try this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import time
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


app = Flask(__name__)


# Task manager executor
_threadpool_cpus = int(os.cpu_count() / 2)
EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max(_threadpool_cpus, 2))


@app.route("/first", methods=["POST"])
def main():
    print("Request received")
    EXECUTOR.submit(func1)
    return json.dumps({"status": True})


def func1():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Print function executed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

This will run the `func1` in a different thread, allowing flask to respond the user without blocking until `func1` is done.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe working with subproccesses is what you need?
You can try something like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(func1())
```

Comment: I am not sure how subprocess is helpful here

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the POST method, that you prescribed. Also 100 seconds sleep time too long :)

```
def func1():
    print("Print function executed1")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Print function executed2")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/first")
def main():
    print("Request received1")
    func1()
    print("Request received2")
    return json.dumps({"status": True})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

Output:

```
Request received1
Print function executed1
Print function executed2
Request received2
```

Comment: My requirement is such that I don;'t want to wait for `func1` to finish it's execution. Above code snippet is just an example. In practice `func1` may take hours to execute

Answer (score 0):

After receiving/executing  a request for function 1, you can set/reset a global status flag/variable(e.g. `flag_func_1 = True`:Request Received ; `False`:Request Executed).

You can monitor the value of the `flag_func_1` and can return `{"status": True}`immediately after setting flag.

Ex: inside main function you can do something like :

```
if(flag_func_1 == True):
  func_1()
  flag_func1 = False
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning, this is not a robust solution**. You should look into distributed queues to persist these requests (for example: RabbitMQ, Kafka, Redis)

That being said... You can use a thread to start the function.

```py
from threading import Thread

@app.route("/first", methods=["GET"])
def main():
    print("Request received")
    Thread(target=func1, args=()).start()
    return json.dumps({"status": True})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need flask to return a response before starting your func1(), you should checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994441/8243797) answer which provides a details about necessary workings of flask.

Otherwise, you can use threading or multiprocessing:

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process #and multiprocessing queue if you use this
import queue #for passing messages between main and func1

message_queue = queue.Queue()
@app.route("/first", methods=["GET"])
def main():
    print("Request received")
    func_thread = Thread(target=func1, args=(), daemon=True).start() #daemon if it needs to die with main program, otherwise daemon=False
    #or func_process = Process(...) #in case

    return json.dumps({"status": True})

def func1():
    ...
    print("func 1 ")
    message_queue.put(...) #if you need to pass something
    message_queue.get(...) #to get something like stopping signal
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do what you're asking is to use the library, multiprocessing.

```
def run_together(*functions):
    processes = []
    for function in functions:
        process = Process(target=function)
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

@app.route("/first", methods=["POST"])
def main():
    print("Request received")

    return run_together(func1, func2)

def func1():
    time.sleep(100)
    print("Print function executed")

def func2():
    return json.dumps({"status": True})
```

I wrote a rough code, I haven't tested it yet. But I hope it helps, cheerio!