# Python and JavaScript basic communication

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet

I have a local HTML page: leaflet.html, which is displayed in an embedded browser inside a python-tkinter application.

Inside leaflet.html there is a simple JavaScript piece of code that contains a function:

```
addMarkerIn(longitude, latitude)
{
}
```

It is not important what this function does, what I need is to call addMarkerIn from python when a specific event occurs. Is it possible to avoid building a full http server environment and communicate through other methods such as named pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add socket connection between js on html page and python backend. Using some library (like socket.io) it seems to be the simplest way.

Comment: socket.io is the best choice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer I wrote once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213379/make-function-not-to-wait-for-other-function-inside-it/59213542#59213542) helps you out?

You could make a function in python called `addMarkerIn` and call it with `subprocess`