# How to execute GPU-related heavy task in the background?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a **server-client** project with `/analyze` URL to analyze something with ***GPU***. The **client** application sends a request with the name of a file to the server through Python's `requests` module.

```
# client.py
import requests

def send_request(host, port, file):
    '''
    host (str): Hostname / IP address,
    port (int): Port 
    '''
    url = f'http://{host}:{port}/analyze'
    body = {'file': file}
    response = requests.post(url, data = body)
    status = response.json()['status']
    print(status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_request("localhost", 5000, "test.h5")
```

When the server gets the request, it starts the analysis which takes around 77-80 seconds per request. I wanted to start the analysis in the background as it takes a lot of time. The server built with `flask` framework.

```
# server.py
import json, logging
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from flask import Flask, request

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

app = Flask(__name__)

EXECUTOR = ProcessPoolExecutor()

def apply_algorithm(file):
    # GPU-related algorithm -- image/video-based analysis (very heavy task)

@app.route('/analyze', methods = ['POST'])
def analyze():
    file = request.form['file']
    message = None
    
    try:
        message = f'Processing started for {file}!'
        EXECUTOR.submit(apply_algorithm, file) 
    except Exception as error:
        message = f'Error: Unable to analyze {file}!'
        logging.warning(f"Error: {error}")
    
    status = {'status': message}

    return json.dumps(status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**Problems:** The client waits for the server's response (for 77-80 seconds as said earlier) before sending the next request to the server. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213379/make-function-not-to-wait-for-other-function-inside-it) already but did not help. I tried with `async` request-response, but it did not help.

- Why the parallel processing (with `ProcessPoolExecutor`) is not working here? (as - it is already running with GPU? or any other reason?). I also tried the `ThreadPoolExecutor` executor but not work.
- Why is the `async` request-response also not working?

Comment: can you post examples of thread pool processor / async functions that didn't work? this is the exact use case they're meant to address

Answer (score 0):

To debug something like this, one approach could be to replace the actual processing with `time.sleep(70)` and return a dummy value to see if it is actually being done correctly in the background in parallel.

1. You could try adding Threaded=True

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

2. You could try to wrap `send_request` an executor.submit
3. You could try specifying the number of workers in `EXECUTOR = ProcessPoolExecutor(10)`
4. You could try using the more basic `ThreadingHTTPServer`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, ThreadingHTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver
socketserver.TCPServer.request_queue_size = 100
import json, logging
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

app = Flask(__name__)

EXECUTOR = ProcessPoolExecutor()

#Server
class functionserver(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        data = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        file = json.loads(data.decode())["file"]

        try:
            message = f'Processing started for {file}!'
            result = EXECUTOR.submit(apply_algorithm, file).result()
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"result":result}).encode())
            self.wfile.flush()
        except Exception as error:
            message = f'Error: Unable to analyze {file}!'
            logging.warning(f"Error: {error}")
            self.send_response(500)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"result":"FAILED"}).encode())
            self.wfile.flush()

        
    def log_message(args,*kwargs):
        return None
        
httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 5000), functionserver)
httpd.serve_forever()
```