# Flask API - perform operation after request with lower priority

Tags: api, rest, flask, flask-restful, thread-priority

my Python Flask-restful API exposes a GET endpoint, `/get_value`, which takes some time to run, and it's crucial that this operation occurs in the fastest time possible. Please consider that multiple requests may occur in sequence from a client application.

Now, I want to store on a DB a log record everytime the `/get_value` endpoint is called, without affecting the API response (writing on a DB is an overhead I can't have while producing the GET response!). The record insertion into the DB has a low priority, and could be done even one day after that the endpoint is called...

Which is the best practice for doing this? Does Flask support a function for that?

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is Redis task queue, check out https://python-rq.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem and I think your question is linked to [Execute a function after Flask returns response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response).

If you read this post and the answers you will find severall solutions to your problem. One of them is to use the decorator [@response.call_on_close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080968/13397655) - [see here for a different example](https://gist.github.com/keleshev/9781384) - which seems to do what you want to do.

If you want to use multithreading, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994441/13397655) should be helpful.

Both - the decorator and multithreading - have the advantage of avoiding  additional dependencies.

HTH